# Adding elements to an ordered list

Tags: c#, data-structures, linked-list

I want to add an element to a linked list so that the list remains sorted. I wrote this function. He's got a place that should be included, but I do not know how to insert the element.

```
public void AddSorted(int num)
{
    Node n = new Node(num);
    Node curr = _first;
    Node curr1 = _first.Link;
    while (curr1.Data < n.Data &&  curr1 != null)
    {
        curr = curr.link;
        curr1= curr1.link;
    }
    // how to add element ???
}
```

Comment: It depends. Singly linked or doubly linked?

Comment: The list is a single link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With the help of my dear friends.
I could write this function.
Below you can see the code :**

`public void AddSorted(int num)
        {
            Node n = new Node(num);
            Node curr = _first;
            if (_first == null || _first.Data >= n.Data)
            {
                n.Link = _first;
                _first = n;
            }
            else
            {
                while (curr.Link != null && curr.Link.Data < n.Data)
                {
                    curr = curr.Link;
                }
                n.Link = curr.Link;
                curr.Link = n;
            }`

Answer (score 1):

You have provided absolutely no context regarding your LinkedList class, so I can only make an educated guess.

Given what I understand from the above code, after traversing to the location you want to insert the new `Node`, you will need to set the link of `Node curr1` (which is the last Node) to the new node object.

```
Node temp = curr1.Link; // store next Node in temporary object
curr1.Link = n; // Insert new Node
```

Remember that you need to set the link of the new node to the next node in the LinkedList in order to continue the LinkedList (if the newly inserted Node is not the last):

```
n.Link = temp;
```

Please let me know if I made a mistake understanding your code, I can then change my answer accordingly.